# How to get the date/time in the original timezone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime

My application receives a "date`T`time`±`timezone" from the API. I'm supposed to show that exact time while formatted with the user defined preference:

```js
var userFormat = "en-US"
var original = "2020-09-01T12:14:05.663-01:23" // strange timezone only to make a point
var date = new Date(original)
console.log(date.toLocaleString(userFormat, {
    hour12:  false   ,
    hour  : "numeric",
    minute: "numeric",
    second: "numeric"}))
// expected: "12:14:05"
```

How can I get a string with the original `12:14:05`, not the local time or the GMT time while avoiding string manipulation?

Comment: You can't. ECMAScript dates are just a time value, an offset in milliseconds from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. They have no concept of timezone. Offset details are retrieved from the host system using [*getTimezoneOffset*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset). On the output side, you can use *toLocaleString* with IANA representative locations for the offset. In any case, you'll have to parse the string yourself to get the offset and apply it.

Answer (score 1):

This may work fine:

```js
  <script type="text/javascript">
        debugger
        var userFormat = "en-US";
        var original = "2020-09-01T12:14:05.663-01:23";
        var time = original.substr(11, 8);
        var HH = time.substr(0, 2);
        var MM = time.substr(3, 2);
        var SS = time.substr(6, 2);
        var date = original.substr(0, 10);
        var YY = date.substr(0, 4);
        var MO = date.substr(5, 2);
        var DD = date.substr(8, 2);

        var Ndate = new Date(YY, MO, DD, HH, MM, SS);

        // sometimes even the US needs 24-hour time
        console.log(Ndate.toLocaleTimeString(userFormat, {
            hour12: false,
        }));
    </script>
```

Comment: i would like to avoid string manipulation, if possible; can we get the original value sent to the Date constructor?

Comment: Code–only answers aren't that helpful. You should explain why the OP has their issue and how your code fixes it. Also, the month should be `MM - 1` not `MO`.

Comment: @RubensFarias the Date Constructor only accepts standard inputs which have to be in numeric format, so I think you can override the Date constructor to accept you original format, one way or another, you cannot avoid string manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

If you always find this kind of date string you can then split the string and find the time like as below.

```
var original = "2020-09-01T12:14:05.663-01:23";
var time = original.split('T')[1].split('.')[0];
```

Comment: I would like to avoid string operations; I also need to format it using the user selected locale, so I need to use a Date object ("12:14", "12:14 PM")

Answer (score -1):

You could trim the timezone from the string before converting it and then use the normal date methods on the result (e.g. `toLocaleString()`).

```js
var userFormat = "en-US"
var original = "2020-09-01T12:14:05.663-01:23"

// Trim off the timezone
var date = new Date(original.split('.')[0]);

console.log(date.toLocaleString(userFormat, { hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric',
  second: 'numeric' 
}))

// Expected: "12:14:05 PM"
```

Comment: you know, actually the server do not send the timezone but the time shown on some clients are off; we thought introducing the timezone would provide a more reliable solution =/

Comment: You could instead include a timezone string in the options object passed to `toLocaleString()` if you know it, so that it formats the time while respecting the timezone.

Comment: This will parse the string as local in most browsers or UTC in some so that it represents a different moment in time for each host with a different offset.